# why smart rounding works differently with map/lapply than without?

Tags: r

I would like to smartly round my results so that it sums up to the same sum after rounding.
Can someone explain me why this is different when I do it with map or lapply?

```
v <- c(
0.9472164,
71.5330771,
27.5197066)

smart.round <- function(x, digits = 0) {
  up <- 10 ^ digits
  x <- x * up
  y <- floor(x)
  indices <- tail(order(x-y), round(sum(x)) - sum(y))
  y[indices] <- y[indices] + 1
  y / up
}

### works correctly
smart.round(v)

### lapply and map is wrong
lapply(v,smart.round)
map(v,smart.round)
```

Comment: `smart.round(v[3])` gives 28... your function depends on the length of the input.

Comment: I dont understand. If I only insert one number yes, It will give 28, same for smart.round(27.5197066)

Comment: I suspect this line is the culprit `indices <- tail(order(x-y), round(sum(x)) - sum(y))`

Answer (score 0):

( I think this is merely a comment, but I have not yet earned my right add comments )

lapply, purrr::map are processing your input sequentially. In your example, lapply takes the first value of `v` and calls `smart.round` then moves on to the second value of `v` and so on ...

in total `smart.round` is called three times, each time without any knowledge of the other two values in `v`.
I'm not entirely sure why you try to use `lapply` here, if this is part of a more complex situation you might want to expand your question.

Comment: ah ok, I didnt realized that it is calling three times v without knowing the other two values in v. so that makes sense, thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I have written my own solution. Definitely a bit cumbersome but it works.. :) My initial goal was just to input a dataframe and output the rounded dataframe.

The whole example here:

```
v <- data.frame(a = c(0.9472164,
                      71.5330771,
                      27.5197066),
                b = c(4.6472164,
                      5.6330771,
                      27.1197066))

smart.round <- function(x, digits = 0) {
  up <- 10 ^ digits
  x <- x * up
  y <- floor(x)
  indices <- tail(order(x-y), round(sum(x)) - sum(y))
  y[indices] <- y[indices] + 1
  y / up
}




rounding_function <- function(input_df) {
  output_df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = ncol(input_df), nrow = nrow(input_df)))
  
  for (i in 1:nrow(input_df)) {
    a = smart.round(as.numeric(input_df[i,]))
    
    for (k in 1:ncol(input_df)) {
      output_df[i,k]=a[k]
    }
    colnames(output_df) = colnames(input_df)
  }
  
  return(output_df)
}

v_rounded <- rounding_function(v)
```

Comment: Ah, ok I understand what you want to achieve .. 

You might consider 
`v_mat_rounded <- smart.round(as.matrix(v))`    

Note that the solutions differ (!). `sum(v_mat_rounded)` is 137, whereas your function yields `sum(v_rounded)`=138  ... in your example  is `sum(v)`=137.4